# Custom button logic Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm creating a script for silent installation of some applications, with a choice box!
I also created a custom button, but I need help to create the button logic.
I thank everyone!

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms


$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.Text ='Softwares Padrão'
$Form.Width = 500
$Form.Height = 300
$Form.AutoSize = $true

$Painel                               = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Panel
$Painel.Height                        = 200
$Painel.Width                         = 154
$Painel.Location                      = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(24,45)
$Painel.BackColor                     = [System.Drawing.ColorTranslator]::FromHtml("#ffffff")


$CheckBox_Selec                       = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$CheckBox_Selec.Text                  = "Selecionar Todos"
$CheckBox_Selec.Width                 = 200
$CheckBox_Selec.Height                = 20
$CheckBox_Selec.AutoSize              = $true
$CheckBox_Selec.Location              = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(34, 20)
$CheckBox_Selec.Checked               = $false
$Form.Controls.Add($CheckBox_Selec)

$CheckBox_Selec1                      = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$CheckBox_Selec1.Text                 = "Winrar"
$CheckBox_Selec1.AutoSize             = $true
$CheckBox_Selec1.Location             = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10, 10)
$CheckBox_Selec1.Checked              = $false
$Form.Controls.Add($CheckBox_Selec1)

$CheckBox_Selec2                      = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$CheckBox_Selec2.Text                 = "Java"
$CheckBox_Selec2.AutoSize             = $true
$CheckBox_Selec2.Location             = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10, 30)
$CheckBox_Selec2.Checked              = $false
$Form.Controls.Add($CheckBox_Selec2)

$CheckBox_Selec3                      = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$CheckBox_Selec3.Text                 = "Adobe Reader"
$CheckBox_Selec3.AutoSize             = $true
$CheckBox_Selec3.Location             = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10, 50)
$CheckBox_Selec3.Checked              = $false
$Form.Controls.Add($CheckBox_Selec3)

$CheckBox_Selec4                      = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$CheckBox_Selec4.Text                 = "Office 2013x32"
$CheckBox_Selec4.AutoSize             = $true
$CheckBox_Selec4.Location             = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10, 70)
$CheckBox_Selec4.Checked              = $false
$Form.Controls.Add($CheckBox_Selec4)

$CheckBox_Selec5                      = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$CheckBox_Selec5.Text                 = "Google Chrome"
$CheckBox_Selec5.AutoSize             = $true
$CheckBox_Selec5.Location             = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10, 90)
$CheckBox_Selec5.Checked              = $false
$Form.Controls.Add($CheckBox_Selec5)

$CheckBox_Selec6                      = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$CheckBox_Selec6.Text                 = "CutePdf"
$CheckBox_Selec6.AutoSize             = $true
$CheckBox_Selec6.Location             = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10, 110)
$CheckBox_Selec6.Checked              = $false
$Form.Controls.Add($CheckBox_Selec6)

$CheckBox_Selec7                      = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$CheckBox_Selec7.Text                 = "Oracle11gx32"
$CheckBox_Selec7.AutoSize             = $true
$CheckBox_Selec7.Location             = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10, 130)
$CheckBox_Selec7.Checked              = $false
$Form.Controls.Add($CheckBox_Selec7)

$CheckBox_Selec8                      = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$CheckBox_Selec8.Text                 = "Piramide"
$CheckBox_Selec8.AutoSize             = $true
$CheckBox_Selec8.Location             = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10, 150)
$CheckBox_Selec8.Checked              = $false
$Form.Controls.Add($CheckBox_Selec8)

$CheckBox_Selec9                      = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$CheckBox_Selec9.Text                 = "Rh3"
$CheckBox_Selec9.AutoSize             = $true
$CheckBox_Selec9.Location             = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10, 170)
$CheckBox_Selec9.Checked              = $false
$Form.Controls.Add($CheckBox_Selec9)

$Button1                              = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button1.Text                         = "Instalar"
$Button1.AutoSize                     = $true
$Button1.Width                        = 60
$Button1.Height                       = 30
$Button1.Location                     = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(290,215)
$Button1.Font                         = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif', 10)
$Button1.Enabled                      = $false
$Form.Controls.Add($Button1)


$Form.controls.AddRange(@($Painel,$CheckBox_Selec,$Button1))
$Painel.controls.AddRange(@($CheckBox_Selec1,$CheckBox_Selec2,$CheckBox_Selec3,$CheckBox_Selec4,$CheckBox_Selec5,$CheckBox_Selec6,$CheckBox_Selec7,$CheckBox_Selec8,$CheckBox_Selec9))

$CheckBox_Selec.Add_CheckStateChanged({$CheckBox_Selec1.Checked = $CheckBox_Selec.Checked})
$CheckBox_Selec.Add_CheckStateChanged({$CheckBox_Selec2.Checked = $CheckBox_Selec.Checked})
$CheckBox_Selec.Add_CheckStateChanged({$CheckBox_Selec3.Checked = $CheckBox_Selec.Checked})
$CheckBox_Selec.Add_CheckStateChanged({$CheckBox_Selec4.Checked = $CheckBox_Selec.Checked})
$CheckBox_Selec.Add_CheckStateChanged({$CheckBox_Selec5.Checked = $CheckBox_Selec.Checked})
$CheckBox_Selec.Add_CheckStateChanged({$CheckBox_Selec6.Checked = $CheckBox_Selec.Checked})
$CheckBox_Selec.Add_CheckStateChanged({$CheckBox_Selec7.Checked = $CheckBox_Selec.Checked})
$CheckBox_Selec.Add_CheckStateChanged({$CheckBox_Selec8.Checked = $CheckBox_Selec.Checked})
$CheckBox_Selec.Add_CheckStateChanged({$CheckBox_Selec9.Checked = $CheckBox_Selec.Checked})

Function Test-AnyButtonCheked {
    if (
        $CheckBox_Selec.Checked -or
        $CheckBox_Selec1.Checked -or
        $CheckBox_Selec2.Checked -or
        $CheckBox_Selec3.Checked -or
        $CheckBox_Selec4.Checked -or
        $CheckBox_Selec5.Checked -or
        $CheckBox_Selec6.Checked -or
        $CheckBox_Selec7.Checked -or
        $CheckBox_Selec8.Checked -or
        $CheckBox_Selec9.Checked 
        ) {
            $Button1.Enabled = $true
        }
        else {
            $Button1.Enabled = $false
      }
}
        
         $CheckBox_Selec.Add_CheckedChanged( { Test-AnyButtonCheked})
         $CheckBox_Selec1.Add_CheckedChanged( { Test-AnyButtonCheked})
         $CheckBox_Selec2.Add_CheckedChanged( { Test-AnyButtonCheked})
         $CheckBox_Selec3.Add_CheckedChanged( { Test-AnyButtonCheked})
         $CheckBox_Selec4.Add_CheckedChanged( { Test-AnyButtonCheked})
         $CheckBox_Selec5.Add_CheckedChanged( { Test-AnyButtonCheked})
         $CheckBox_Selec6.Add_CheckedChanged( { Test-AnyButtonCheked})
         $CheckBox_Selec7.Add_CheckedChanged( { Test-AnyButtonCheked})
         $CheckBox_Selec8.Add_CheckedChanged( { Test-AnyButtonCheked})
         $CheckBox_Selec9.Add_CheckedChanged( { Test-AnyButtonCheked})


 [void] $Form.ShowDialog()
```

This is my structure, I know it's not in the best practices but it's running very well!

I would like to install the applications according to the checkbox chosen by the user!
I would like to configure the button so that if the user selects, "install all" he will install all applications or just the chosen checkbox.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: A few hints to improve: - make a function to create the buttons; - add all buttons to a collection and call `Any()` on the collection to enable the button. If you can, it may be easier to go with `xaml` rather than `windows.forms`

Comment: Thanks for the attention friend, I'll try that way!

Comment: Thank you my friend! I will try to improve following your tip!